# Data transformer- Can't Create an Object- Cannot create an instance from serialized data

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create an object in Symfony PHP.
it returns me:

```
"Cannot create an instance of Foo from serialized data because its constructor requires parameter \"id\" to be present."
```

the body request:

```
{
    "name": "aaa bbb",
    "id": "e5f348a0-11d5-4d49-a5bc-2c9b5abf3ad7",
    "type": "1",
}
```

my endpoint:

```
'copy_object' => [
            'method' => 'POST',
            'path' => '/api/copy_object',
            'input' => Foo::class,        
        ]
```

my transform function:

```
    /**
     * @var Foo
     *                  {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function transform($data, string $to, array $context = [])
    {

        $this->validator->validate($data);
        /** @var Foo $data */
        return $data->createNewBasedOnThat();
    }
```

my constructor:

```
    private function __construct(
        /**
         * @var string
         * @ORM\Id()
         * @ORM\Column(type="guid", unique=true)
         */
        private string $id,
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
         */
        private string $name,

        TypeEnum $type,
    )
```

Maybe someone knows this problem?
Thank you!!

Comment: Doesn't your class implement Serializable interface?

Comment: No. do you think I need it?

Comment: Consider the first comment in the documentation of Serializable, it demonstrates how you can serialize your class while having a constructor with parameters...  https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php#118264